# Sum and conditions in linear programming - Cplex // OPL

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, ilog, opl

Is there an easy way to apply a condition into a sum in OPL or to get around this problem ?

For example is it possible to do something like :

```
 forall (i in Factories)
    forall( j in Time)
        Stock[i][j] == sum (i_ in Factories where j-LeadTime[i_][i]>0) (expression)
```

The only way I found to get around this problem is to extend my dataset in order to avoid out of range exception but in my case that don't make any sense so I would like to apply a condition into the sum before.

Comment: No LeadTime is not a variable. I don't have any errors because I am not using the code above. This code is incorrect as you can't use a where or if conditions into a sum but my question is : Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

The `:` operator is the correct way to add conditions to a sum statement.  You want something like the following.

```
 forall (i in Factories)
    forall( j in Time)
        Stock[i][j] == sum (i_ in Factories : j-LeadTime[i_][i]>0) (expression)
```

`where` isn't part of the OPL language.